# Is is possible to git branch from master while on a different branch?

Tags: git

Let's say I am on develop branch, and I need to do an urgent bugfix, so normally, I would need to

```
# on develop
git checkout master
git checkout -b bugfix/blah
```

but is it possible to branch without jumping to master first

```
# on develop
git checkout -b bugfix/blah --from master
```

Comment: Just lose the `--from`

Comment: I saw this on the manual `git branch [--set-upstream | --track | --no-track] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]` is that the start-point?

Comment: From the `man git-branch`:  "
 <start-point>
           The new branch head will point to this commit. It may be given as a
           branch name, a commit-id, or a tag. If this option is omitted, the
           current HEAD will be used instead.
"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are talking about this

```
git checkout -b bugfix/blah master
```